# How to optimize a query in a one to many scenario when i have a fulltext index on a column?

Tags: mysql, relationship

My `paintings` table looks like this

```
|  id  | artist_id |    name 
|  1   |     7     |  landscape painting
|  2   |     15    |  flowers painting
|  3   |     15    |  scuffed painting
```

The `artist_id` is indexed and the `name` has a `fulltext` index on it. The table contains about 10M record.

Queries that match the `name` agains some keywords are ok:

```
select * from `paintings` where match (`name`) against ('+scuffed*' in boolean mode) limit 10;
10 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

But when I sometimes want to only check for a certain painting done by a certain artist:

```
select * from `paintings` where `artist_id` = 15 and match (`name`) against ('+scuffed*' in boolean mode) limit 10;
7 rows in set (0.40 sec)
```

As you can see it takes 10x longer to run the query when I include the `artist_id`. I also tried running a nested query in order to get only paintings that have specific ids:

```
select * from `paintings` where id in (SELECT id from paintings where artist_id = 15) and match (`name`) against ('+scuffed*' in boolean mode) limit 10;
7 rows in set (0.44 sec)
```

This ended up being even slower.

How can this query be optimized to work well with and without a where clause on the `artist_id`?

Thank you!

Comment: If just the match condition is fast enough, nest them the other way, with match in the subquery and artist id in the outer qiery

Comment: can you show me how that's done? i wrote this query (took 20 sec): `select * from paintings where artist_id = 729 and id in (select id from paintings where match (`name`) against ('+scuffed*' in boolean mode))
limit 10;`

Answer (score 0):

Run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see how the query is performed.

I think your second query is as optimal is can be.  MySQL will perform the `MATCH` first, then check any other conditions.

You could add `INDEX(artist_id)`, but I don't think that will help.

**More**

Let me provide another approach, then talk through the pros an cons.

```
PRIMARY KEY(artist_id, id),
INDEX(id),
FULLTEXT(name),

-- When searching _only_ by `name`:
WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('+string' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

-- When searching by artist _and_ name:
WHERE artist_id = 123
  AND name LIKE '%string%';
```

Comments:

- Without the artist, you get the full speed of FULLTEXT.
- With artist, you abandon FULLTEXT (because it seems not to work for your dataset) and switch to the composite index, plus need to look only at those rows with the given artist_id.
- `id` needs to be indexed to keep `AUTO_INCREMENT` happy; a simple `INDEX(id)` suffices.
- The `PRIMARY KEY` *must* be unique; including `id` suffices.
- *Starting* the PK with `artist_id clusters the rows for a given artist together, thereby speeding the query up (some for small tables, a lot for big tables).
- This requires that you create two different queries, but that is probably not a big problem.
- For an artist that has a lot of works, it may be 'too' slow -- because it is failing to use `FULLTEXT`.
- `FULLTEXT` and `LIKE` have different rules for what will/won't match.  So you may get different answers.
- Another recent Question discussed why `AGAINST('... +the ...' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` never finds any rows.
- `AGAINST("+color +purple")` will find `purple color`, but `LIKE '%color purple%` won't.
- Be careful about benchmarking any approaches -- the performance will depend on how many works an artist has, and many other un-obvious differences.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a COMPOSITE INDEX KEY consisting of columns (id and artist_id) to speed up your query:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE paintings ADD INDEX cmp_id_artist_id (id, artist_id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM paintings;
+-----------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name         | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+-----------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| paintings |          1 | cmp_id_artist_id |            1 | id          | A         |           3 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| paintings |          1 | cmp_id_artist_id |            2 | artist_id   | A         |           3 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| paintings |          1 | ftindex_name     |            1 | name        | NULL      |           3 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | FULLTEXT   |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+-----------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And now you can test again your 2nd query:

```
mysql> select * from `paintings` where `artist_id` = 15 and match (`name`) against ('+scuffed*' in boolean mode) limit 10;
+----+-----------+------------------+
| id | artist_id | name             |
+----+-----------+------------------+
|  3 |        15 | scuffed painting |
+----+-----------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Do i have to drop the other indexes that are currently on my table? `artist_id` index and `name` fulltext index are my current indexes

Comment: Drop only artist_id index. Because now It will become part of composite index. Full text index will stay the same. Do not touch it, please!

Comment: Ok, I've created the index and the query is now twice as fast but still quiet slow compared to when no `artist_id` is specified.

Comment: Now do the 2nd test. Remove composite key: Make id field Primary Key! The others will just the same as before! Please do it and make a comparison. As 3rd case, Make composite key you defined as Primary Key, and test again!

Comment: Now I removed the composit key, only the `fulltext` on `name` index is left and the select time doesn't change `10 rows in set (0.66 sec)`.

Comment: No! You should define 3 indexes: id : Primary Key, name = Full Text and artist_id : index

Comment: Done that now. The result is slightly slower (`0.7 sec` vs `0.66 sec` with composite index).

Comment: OK. Now Final Test___ Primary Key(id, artist_id) , name = FullText. After testing this, you can decide which one to choose:)

Comment: NO -- The speed of `MATCH` requires a `FULLTEXT` index.  A composite index is _NOT_ appropriate here.

Comment: We do not focus only on FullText index here! we even didn't make any change on full text indexed column. We focus on the overall performance of the query.